# ASP Core BundleConfig. CSS not being applied to view

Tags: css, asp.net-core, razor

I have a ASP Core project and have added a `bundleconfig.json` to the project base. Within the `bundleconfig.json` I have added the following code for bootstrap.css

```
{
  "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bundles/bootstrap.css",
  "inputFiles": [
    "wwwroot/css/Plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"
  ]
},
```

When I build the project I can see the `bootstrap.css` file in the specified path within the project. I have placed the `bootstrap.css` file on my `_Layout.cshtml` view within the `<head>` tag.

```
<environment include="Development,Staging,Production">
    <style src="/css/bundles/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"></style>
</environment>
```

When I load up my site none of the bootstrap css styling being applied. If I view the source using chrome dev tools I can see

```
<style src="/css/bundles/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"></style>
```

and when I click on it I can see all the correct css code is present in the file.

I have also installed the BundlerMinifier.Core nuget package and the Bundler & Minifier extension as I seen others suggest on other posts.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be  `<link href="/css/bundles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`